# Why does this code detects images as video and how can I fix it?

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg

This method is detecting `.jpg` pictures as video. Why is that? How can I fix it?

```
def is_video(self) -> bool:
    try:
        res = self.video_metadata['codec_type'] == 'video'
        logger.info(f"Video.is_video() -> {res}")
        return res
    except:
        return False
```

I'm getting the metadata with

```
ffmpeg.probe(self.path, select_streams = stream)['streams'][0]
```

I'm using the metadata for more things, that's why I've used ffmpeg in this method.

Comment: `ffmpeg` is a video library, so it's kind of natural for it to treat everything as a video.

Comment: If you must distinguish 'image` from `video`, check the number of frames in addition.

Comment: FFmpeg supported streams types are "video", "audio", "subtitles", "data" (and "attachment" stream). All types of images (JPEG, PNG, TIFF, BMP...) have `'codec_type'` = `'video'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for number of frames greater than 1 to distinguish between image and video.

```
def is_video(self) -> bool:
    try:
        res = (self.video_metadata['codec_type'] == 'video'
               and int(self.video_metadata['nb_frames']) > 1)
        logger.info(f"Video.is_video() -> {res}")
        return res
    except:
        return False
```

Comment: please add why this fixes your issue so future developers with the same issue can know why this is a valid solution